package org.jsoup does not exist
I am trying to import Jsoup using Maven but for some reason it is not seeing that it is an added dependency. I have the following code:
->Java:
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
public class TestClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "Google.com";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    }
}

and
->pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestFile</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

When I run the java file, I get the error code "package org.jsoup does not exist. I'm not sure what the problem is.
I tried downloading Jsoup instead, and then adding it to Project Structure -> Modules, but this did not work either. I simply want the code to run without any errors.

Have you tried compiling your code without intelij? What happens if your run mvn clean install in your root project folder (where your pom.xml is defined)?

Change to the directory where the pom file resides from a console. Ensure jdk/bin and maven/bin folders are on path. Execute mvn clean compile -U and check if there are any errors.
